# How can I retrieve the k highest values in a data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, max

How can I retrieve the k highest values in a data frame in pandas?

For example, given the DataFrame:

```
               b         d         e
Utah    1.624345 -0.611756 -0.528172
Ohio   -1.072969  0.865408 -2.301539
Texas   1.744812 -0.761207  0.319039
Oregon -0.249370  1.462108 -2.060141
```

Generated with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('bde'), 
                     index=['Utah', 'Ohio', 'Texas', 'Oregon'])
print(frame)
```

The 3  highest values in the data frame are:

1. 1.744812
2. 1.624345
3. 1.462108

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use  [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) +   [`pandas.Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), e.g.:

```
In [183]: frame.stack().nlargest(3)
Out[183]:
Texas   b    1.744812
Utah    b    1.624345
Oregon  d    1.462108
dtype: float64
```

or:

```
In [184]: frame.stack().nlargest(3).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[184]:
0    1.744812
1    1.624345
2    1.462108
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, I had missed [`pandas.DataFrame.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Fun with `numpy`

```
np.partition(df.values.ravel(), df.size - 3)[-1:-4:-1]

array([ 1.744812,  1.624345,  1.462108])
```

---

**Breakdown**

1. `np.partition` splits the a 1-d array into smallest `k` and largest `n - k`
2. I need to get at `df`'s values in a 1-d way
3. `n` in this case is the total size of `df`, `k` is 3
4. `[-1:-4:-1]` means, start at `-1`, go all the way up to `-4` but not including `-4` by taking steps of size `-1`... translates into the last 3 elements starting with the last first.

---

```
#  1                   2           3        4
#  |                   |           |        |
#  v                   v           v        v
np.partition(df.values.ravel(), df.size - 3)[-1:-4:-1]
```

Comment: wow - it looks really nice! it will take me some time to understand it...

Comment: I just made it worse (-:

Comment: there is one thing i don't understand - why `df.size - 3`? Could you please explain it?

Comment: `np.partition` inherently breaks up array in ascending order (smallest `k`, largest `n - k`).  So I have to specify that I want the partition to be in descending order.  Since that option doesn't exist, I have to make my partition be where the left overs are of size `3`.  To do that I make sure the first partition is at `df.size - 3` leaving 3 at the end.

Comment: so `np.partition(frame.values.ravel(), 3)[::-1][:3]` would work as well, but ot's not that efficient - right?

Comment: No, because, the first three would be the 3 smallest, the next 9 are the largest 9 in no particular order.  It's the "no particular order" that gives us the Big-O advantage over sorting.  So we need to break it into smallest 9 and then the last 3 will be the largest 3.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the other nice solutions, this also works:

```
>>>df_values = frame.values.ravel()                                        
>>>df_values[df_values.argsort()[:3]]
array([-2.3015387 , -2.06014071, -1.07296862])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

yet another way:

```
a = frame.values.flatten()
a.sort()
a[-3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort all items in the frame, select the last 3 items.

Finally, flip the order of the array.

```
 np.flipud(
     np.sort(frame, axis=None)[-3:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can using `operator`, `functools`

```
sorted(functools.reduce(operator.concat, df.values.tolist()),reverse=True)[0:3]
```